# How to fix user profile url when user's name is missing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have user signup in feature using Devise gem. I am getting only the value of `email id and password` via user signup form.

If, I go to one the user's show page, the url is not very descriptive of its content. It show `primary id's` value in the url like below

```
http://localhost:3000/users/17
```

Than, I decided to overwrite the default behaviour using `friendly_id` Gem.

Hence, I didn’t get the name of the user in the signup form. Now, I don't have any other value to use in the url.

What shall I do in this case. Please suggest some idea. How do I handle this issue!...

Comment: Add a username field? Do you allow a user to see one another's profiles?

Comment: But, we don't need user's name date; any other suggestion.

Comment: No, I don't allow to see other's profile.

Comment: You are allowing the users to sign up without a name? That seems akward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> No, I don't allow to see other's profile

We have this setup:

[image]

This gives us the ability to call the `edit` and `update` actions of the `users` controller with the url: `url.com/profile`

You'd be able to set it up as follows:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def edit
      #use current_user
   end

   def update
      redirect_to profile_path if current_user.update profile_params
   end
end

#app/views/users/edit.html.erb
<%= form_for current_user do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field ....... %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This sounds like what you need.

---

If you wanted to set up `friendly_id` without the comparative `username` etc, we use a `Profile` model which allows you to add a username if you wish:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :profile
   before_create :build_profile
   delegate :name, to: :profile
end

#app/models/profile.rb
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user

   extend FriendlyId
   friendly_id :name
end
```

We then manage to look up the `profile` with a little bit of a hack:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @user = Profile.find(params[:id]).user #-> friendly_id looks up the :name column in users
   end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it a singular resource

```
resource :user
```

Then it'll just route to `/user`

In your form you'll need to make the url explicit as rails won't be able to infer it's a singular resource

```
<%= form_for @user, url: user_path %>
```